# Rails 7 Importmaps not working with Rails -

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I've had a miserable time getting JS to run in Rails 7 without extra frameworks (React, Hotwire, etc)

Long story short, I finally got it up and running in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Safari, showing the following errors:

```
[Error] TypeError: Module specifier, 'application' does not start with "/", "./", or "../". Referenced from http://localhost:3315
[Log] ^^ Module TypeError above is polyfilled and can be ignored ^^ (es-module-shims.min.debug-0969e926293ef468e580fe8c9d79cfa6dd354f2409e238d4639c375dcab57e3c.js, line 1)
```

I previously fixed this (in Chrome) by adding/referencing the importmap tags in the main layout and using `pin "application", preload: true` in the `config/importmap.rb`

It says the TypeError can be ignored, but none of the JS is being run. I DO see the importmap in the rendered `head` as expected, and the `sources` correctly show all of the expected JS, but it's not bring run for some reason. Works perfectly in Chrome, but Safari it doesn't run.

JS written directly in the `application.js` will run, but `imports` and functions pulled from imports do not.

Has anybody else run into this or know what it could be from?

Answer (score 2):

False alarm- it turns out that the "document ready" function I was using was not being attached because in Safari there was a race condition where the "DOMContentLoaded" event listener was being attached only after the document had loaded.

This was fixed by doing a check in the function to immediately run the callback if the DOM is already loaded:

```
// OLD - Works in Chrome, but not Safari
window.domReady = function(callback) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    callback()
  }, { once: true })
}

// NEW - working with Safari!
window.domReady = function(callback) {
  if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
    callback()
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      callback()
    }, { once: true })
  }
}
```